# Delete command not removing records from Aerospike

Tags: aerospike

I'm using the following method from Java Aerospike client in order to delete records/bins:

```scala
 def truncate(startTime: Long, durableDelete: Boolean): List[AtomicInteger] = {
    logger.info(s"truncate($startTime) Triggered")

    val calendar = new GregorianCalendar()
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(startTime)

    // Define Scan and Write Policies
    val scanPolicy = new ScanPolicy()
    scanPolicy.filterExp = Exp.build(Exp.le(Exp.lastUpdate(), Exp.`val`(calendar)))
    val writePolicy = client.writePolicyDefault
    writePolicy.durableDelete = durableDelete

    // Scan all records such as LUT <= startTime
    for (recoverBins <- config.binsToRecover) yield {
      val recordCount = new AtomicInteger(0)
      client.scanAll(scanPolicy, recoverBins.namespace, recoverBins.set, new ScanCallback() {
        override def scanCallback(key: Key, record: Record): Unit = {
          recoverBins.specificBins match {
            // multi-bin scenario
            case Some(specificBins) =>
              specificBins foreach (bin => client.put(writePolicy, key, Bin.asNull(bin)))
              logger.debug(s"Bins $specificBins of record: $record with key: $key are set to NULL")

            // single-bin scenario
            case None =>
              client.delete(writePolicy, key)
              logger.debug(s"Record: $record with key: $key DELETED")
          }
          recordCount.incrementAndGet()
        }
      })
```

duruableDelete is set to true

The problem is that when I'm removing bins (`Bin.asNull`) i can see the results immediately but when checking the "deleted" key i can still see them (`aql> select * from ns.set where PK = <ShouldBeDeleted>`

any ideas why? what I'm doing wrong?

---

Another question: How does `duruableDelete` is preventing "Zombie records"? what happening behind the scene?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Aerospike Enterprise Edition?

Comment: @pgupta yes, just note that if i'm deleting the single bin with Bin.asNull its works

Comment: You have to delete all bins in the record for the record to be deleted. So are the "specificBins" covering all the bins in the record when you set each to null?  (BTW, you are creating a separate write transaction (put()) for each bin.. not the best performant .. but that is besides the point.)

Comment: the problem is actually not on the `specificBins`, they really delete the bins and if its the last bin its replace it on commit with null and put tombstone, the problem is on the `client.delete` for single bin, i don't understand why - btw, do you know more bulk approach? since its making request for each record, its will be great! :)

Comment: single put call can take more than on bin.  so do all bins in one go. public final void put(WritePolicy policy,
                      Key key,
                      Bin... bins)

Comment: Got it, `client.put(writePolicy, key, bins.map(Bin.asNull(_)) : _*)` , any other recommendation regarding preformance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235672/discussion-between-pgupta-and-zvi-mints).

Comment: I'm there, thanks @pgupta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zombie Record: A record that was earlier removed from the cluster but comes back alive in the cluster at a later time. There are various scenarios under which this can happen. Durably deleting records prevents all but one of these scenarios.  Durable deletes do this by saving a tombstone in the cluster.  Example: You have a record on master and replica. You shutdown master node, then delete record in the cluster non-durably. When you restart the master, the record will be resurrected. If you durably deleted, the cluster will have a  tombstone (assuming you restarted master within tombstone life period - 1 day default) and when incoming master compares record metadata upon joining the cluster, it will not resurrect the its copy of the record.

Comment: Can you provide an example for how it can happen? i guess that non durable delete just drop the index but then when the cold start is happening it can re-create the data on the index, is that correct? if so, how tombstone preventing that? and how can i know if record is actually a tombstone? is that null records? (via AQL/client)

Comment: You cannot "read" a tombstone into a client. You can see count of tombstones in your system - use $ asadm -e info  ==> ns1         ip-172-31-65-87.ec2.internal:3000   1.000     1        (0.000,  0.000,  0.000)      (1.000,  0.000,  0.000)      (0.000,  0.000)     0    (Here I created one record and durbaly deleted it, 1 master record tombstone shows up)

Comment: I am not sure why client.delete() is not working for you. In AQL, when you read the record back, do:   aql> set record_print_metadata true   and then watch the generation count before and after. Wondering is some other part of your code is recreating the record. Tombstone gets the next gen count so if record is recreated its gen is +1 from tombstone, so if you see higher gen count, then that is a clue.

Comment: after running the `truncate` method all the records which i inject before are deleted, but when I'm doing `select * from ns.set` i can see them, any idea why its happening?

Comment: If you are a licensed EE customer, please open a support case. There is something trivial that we are missing in this picture.